# VBA: Copy-Paste Into One Worksheet Macro Error

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy the columns from all tabs (worksheets) in a workbook into the first empty column in Sheet1. Last week, I wrote the below macro:

```
Option Explicit

Dim i As Integer

Sub GICF_Confimit_CopyPaste_Sheet()
    For i = 2 To 50 Step 1
        Sheets(i).Activate
        Range("C1").Select
        Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
        Selection.Copy
        Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
        Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Offset(0, 1).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    Next i
End Sub
```

This worked fine then, but now it is throwing an error saying that it cannot paste and that I should select one cell and click paste or select a shape of the same size. It is a lot of data (150+ columns from each tab), but this worked for me last week and now seems to have broken, despite my not changing anything.

Would anyone be able to help?

Comment: I should add that the issue seems to be that my file won't let me go over 256 columns. I am running Excel 2010, saved the file as a .xlsx and did not encounter this same issue last week.

Comment: You saved the file as a .xlsx, but did it originate as a .xls? If so, you can't actually "convert it" to .xlsx for purposes of the size limits. You will need to create a new file as an xlsx in order to have the increased column limit of 16,384.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is very clear that the copied range is not same as the selected paste. I suggest just select the cell and paste it.

```
Option Explicit

Dim i As Integer

Sub GICF_Confimit_CopyPaste_Sheet()
For i = 2 To 50 Step 1
    Sheets(i).Activate
    Range("C1").Select
    Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
Next i
End Sub
```